# LTSP/Ubuntu 16.04: unable to login

Tags: login, ltsp

I installed a LTSP server on top of Kubuntu 16.04 on a PC.
The thin client (Asus Eee PC) boots as expected from the network and I get the ldm login screen. I enter my credentials but then I get a black screen during few seconds and it loops back to the login screen. It seems to be unable to start the X session.
I used to have LTSP working flawlessly on a 14.04 Kubuntu but i decided to upgrade to 16.04 one week ago...

I spent hours trying to solve it without success.

In the sys log file I found this:

> "failed to create session: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service not found"

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search I found the fix:
LDM tries to start by default a session on the server using "gnome-session-fallback". But if you are running KDE (Kubuntu) on the server you don't have gnome installed and it fails. To fix it you have to add a line in the lts.conf file:
LDM_SESSION="plasma"
I suppose it is a bug
I hope it will help some of you.